# Displaying value in only last row of a partition

Tags: sql, database, window-functions

I am generating a transcript for students in a database. I am using window functions to provide running semester and cumulative GPAs. My query is as follows:

```
SELECT FIRSTNAME, COURSENAME, SCORE, MAX_SCORE, SEMESTER, SGPA, AVG(ROUND(SGPA,2)) OVER (PARTITION BY FIRSTNAME ORDER BY SEMESTER) AS CGPA

FROM(

SELECT FIRSTNAME, COURSENAME, SCORE, MAX_SCORE, SEMESTER, ROUND((SEM_TOTAL_SCORE * 4/SEM_TOTAL_MAX_SCORE ),2) AS SGPA FROM(

SELECT FIRSTNAME, COURSENAME, SCORE, MAX_SCORE, SEMESTER,
SUM(SCORE)
OVER (PARTITION BY FIRSTNAME ORDER BY SEMESTER) AS SEM_TOTAL_SCORE,
SUM(MAX_SCORE)
OVER (PARTITION BY FIRSTNAME ORDER BY SEMESTER) AS SEM_TOTAL_MAX_SCORE
FROM STUDENT_GRADE_COURSE
)
);
```

I get the following results:

[image]

Now the results are correct. But I do not want to display the SGPA and CGPA on each row. Rather I want them to be displayed only on the last row of the partition which in this case is the semester. So on last row of semester 1 and semester 2 I see the gpas...on the other rows nothing should be displayed in those columns.

How can I do that?

Comment: SQL tables and results sets represent *unordered* sets.  There is no "last row of the partition" (outside the definition of the particular column).  Usually, this type of transformation is done in the application layer.

Comment: I am not sure but you might be using wrong word partition here, (word partition has different meaning in database) I think you should use range word.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yeah that makes sense. Now realized this was a dumb question :)